# picture in wpf (only click in circle not in squre, the circle is inside of square)

Tags: wpf

I have a picture in my program

In this picture, there is a square and a circle in the square

In my program, when user click on the circle, my animation will execute.(only click in circle Not in square, the circle is inside of square). please help me to write this code

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are these custom drawn shapes on a single canvas (or other control) or are these separate shapes that happen to overlap?  If they're just shapes, just perform a hit test on the circle only or check the mouse over properties and that's it.  If not, consider switching over.

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=d197f51a-de07-4edf-9cba-1f1b4a22110d&displaylang=en) you could write this fully in Xaml using a [ControlStoryboardAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723988%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

```
<Window ...
    xmlns:Custom="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity" 
    xmlns:im="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media;assembly=Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"
    >
   <Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard1">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.75"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleY)" Storyboard.TargetName="ellipse">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="0.75"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Canvas Margin="56,104,114,248">
        <Rectangle Fill="#FFF4F4F5" Height="157" Canvas.Left="60" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="51" Width="170"/>
    <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse" Fill="#FFE48A06" Height="115" Canvas.Left="89" Stroke="Black" Canvas.Top="76" Width="119" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Ellipse.RenderTransform>
    <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <im:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource Storyboard1}"/>
        </Custom:EventTrigger>
    </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
</Window>
```

BTW: I made this for Windows Phone so it might need a little adjustment for WPF.

Comment: Hi Erno 
for example: in USA map, when the cursor of mouse come close on California, the map of California become bigger and when I click on California, the information of California be seen in new page.

Comment: @Mohsen: Then replace the `<Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">` with `<Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseMouse">` and subscribe to the click event to naviage to another page.

Comment: BTW: you might want to place this logic in a style so you can apply it to all states.

Comment: my problem is selecting the picture

Comment: how to set the mouse property only for California

Comment: You mean for the click on the ellipse? Subscribe to the MouseUp event of the California shape or (again) add a Invoke(?) behavior to the shape.

Comment: thanks Erno.
Regarding to your prompt guidance, I have solved my problem.